# Binding height/width from a Wpf Frame with Prism 6

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, prism

I have a Frame inside my ViewMain.xaml which I need to read the height/width from it. In the ViewModel I've got 2 prism properties and a command that should get called thru a ObservesProperty. The command does some calculations with the height/width. I tried to bind the height/width with all the Modes (TwoWay etc.).

What I have is this:
ViewMain.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.Views.ViewMain"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         >
<Grid>
      ...
      <Frame Content="{Binding MainGrid}" Margin="0,30,0,0" Height="{Binding GridHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="{Binding GridHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the ViewMainViewModel.cs:

```
...
public class ViewMainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand SizeUpdateCommand { get; set; }

    private Grid _mainGrid;
    public Grid MainGrid
    {
        get { return _mainGrid; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _mainGrid, value); }
    }
    private double _gridHeight = 300;
    public double GridHeight
    {
        get { return _gridHeight; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _gridHeight, value); }
    }
    private double _gridWidth = 420;
    public double GridWidth
    {
        get { return _gridWidth; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _gridWidth, value); }
    }
    public ViewMainViewModel()
    {
        Grid newGrid = new Grid();
        MainGrid = newGrid;
        SizeUpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute, CanExecute).ObservesProperty(() => GridHeight).ObservesProperty(() => GridWidth);
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }

    private bool CanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }
...
```

Does someone spot the issue or what I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Prism issue.  This has to do with how trying to bind to the Frame's height/width works in WPF.  If all you want to do is track size changes of the frame in your ViewModel via a Command, then I would recommend a completely different approach.  Just use the InvokeCommandAction:

```
    <Frame>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SizeUpdateCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="NewSize" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Frame>
```

Then change your DelegateCommand to be:

```
public DelegateCommand<object> SizeUpdateCommand { get; set; }

    private void Execute(object size)
    {
        var newSize = (Size)size;
    }

    private bool CanExecute(object size)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Now anytime the Frame size changes your VM will know about it.

P.S. Don't ever create or reference a UI objects in your VM.  Not even a DependencyObject.  Get rid of your MainGrid property and any reference to a Grid.

Comment: I found a nearly similiar solution yestarday, still thanks :) About the PS, I need to inject a generated Grid from a algorithm into the Frame, are there any other solutions then?

Comment: Without knowing the scenario exactly, its hard to say.  There are many ways to accomplish this, and using a Behavior is the first one that pops into my mind.  Also, Why use a frame in the first place?  What are you getting out of it?  If it is for navigation, you would have more power and flexibility if you use Prism's navigation framework.

Comment: I need to study behavior first then, but I will check it out. The reason of the Frame is to get something in my View, where I can inject the generated Grid. I have more UI in this View, so I cant do it directly into the Content of the View itself. The generated Grid isnt for navigation, I am already using Prism's navigation and it's great

Comment: ah yeah and the generated Grid needs to have the size of the Frame or the Window to calculate how much data can be displayed